# How to revoke running permission to unresponsive script in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, unresponsive

In a certain website, a JS script causes the Firefox browser in my computer to crash.

Stopping that script will allow me to access the website flawlessly, but I accidentally allowed it to keep running, and now the prompt won't appear again, so whenever I try to access that website, Firefox will crash.

I'd like to have the chance to revoke the permission on that script, so it will work from now on, but unfortunatelly, I havent found any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the site behaves differently than before you allowed JS, likely it left cookies or super-cookies. Clean out all cookies for that site from `Tools` | `Options` | `Privacy & Security`| `Cookies and Site Data` | `Manage Data`.

If you'd rather have a convenient extension to clean up cookies, you might try [StoragErazor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/storagerazor/) or [Clear Browsing Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clear-browsing-data). Be careful to *not* clear passwords or other essential data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as said, It's not cookies related. 
There´s a script (webcomponents polyfill, I think) that I allowed.(don't ask me again) and I need the prompt again.
See the same issue here:
https://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/977994

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, rolling back to Firefox 42, allegedly a version that didn't implement that feature yet; then after updating the problem should be gone.

A reinstall though won't answer my question, will probably solve the issue.

.